# Entity Framework Core .Include on related entities but wanting one of the Includes to be conditional?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am loading a customer and its related entities using the following (this is .NET Core 3.1 and Entity Framework Core).

```
                var customer = loyaltyContext.Customer
                    .Include(c => c.ContactInformation)
                    .Include(c => c.Address)
                    .Include(c => c.MarketingPreferences)
                    .Include(c => c.ContentTypePreferences)
                    .Include(c => c.ExternalCards)
                    .Where(c => c.CustomerInternalId == customerInternalId).First();
```

However, a customer can have more than one ExternalCard, but only one card will be 'ACTIVE', so in pseudo code, what I'd really like to do is:

```
                    var customer = loyaltyContext.Customer
                        .Include(c => c.ContactInformation)
                        .Include(c => c.Address)
                        .Include(c => c.MarketingPreferences)
                        .Include(c => c.ContentTypePreferences)
                        .Include(c => c.ExternalCards WHERE CardStatus == "ACTIVE")
                        .Where(c => c.CustomerInternalId == customerInternalId).First();
```

So I don't return the last 10 cards the customer had (but which are now inactive). Is this possible in any way using EF Core? I can't seem to find the right syntax for this. At least not without having to create additional queries (whereas I'd rather just bring back less data to begin with).

ExternalCards is an ICollection< ExternalCards > as one customer can have many cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering `include` option is not available in EF Core version <= 3.1. It's a new feature in **EF Core 5.0**. Here it is for EF Core 5.0 : [Filtered Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include)

For EF Core <=3.1, You have to do the filtering in memory as follows:

```
var customer = loyaltyContext.Customer
                    .Include(c => c.ContactInformation)
                    .Include(c => c.Address)
                    .Include(c => c.MarketingPreferences)
                    .Include(c => c.ContentTypePreferences)
                    .Include(c => c.ExternalCards)
                    .Where(c => c.CustomerInternalId == customerInternalId).First();

customer.ExternalCards = customer.ExternalCards.Where(ec => ec.CardStatus == "ACTIVE").ToList();
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that when you save changes back to the context, it deletes all cards that are not ACTIVE from the database :S. I'm assuming because we changed customer.ExternalCards to be only the one ACTIVE card.

Comment: Okay! then use `AsNoTracking` in the first query. It will prevent deleting.

Comment: Maybe it would help if i explained what i'm trying to do. Customer is getting a card replaced, and customer can be attached to (example) 10 cards, 9 inactive, 1 active. Active 1 is lost. Card replaced. We want to set the 1 active to inactive, and insert a new active card. So i'm guessing I'll just need to use AsNoTracking on above, and create separate insert of new card? (at moment i just link new card to existing customer and save)

Comment: Yes! Without this no option available for now. Good Luck!